# Is there a way to avoid timeout errors in Google Sheets when Scripting Imports

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a few large databases kept on sheets right now. We have them connected for visualization purposes to many other sheets. We have previously had an Update Script that would copy & Paste info from the main large databases to a sheet within each associated Visualization. This update button has broken down and we have been receiving Timeout errors when trying to call that spreadsheet. Is there a way to get around timeout errors on the following Code?

Specifically, the timeout errors seem to occur on the
`var igs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('*URL_HERE*');`. If there is a way to reduce the stress and increase the effectiveness of this SpreadSheet App Connection I would love to know! Thanks for the time

```
function UpdateIGS(){
  var ssopen = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var opentable = ssopen.getSheetByName('IGS Open');
  opentable.getRange('A:BT').clearContent();

  var ssclosed = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var closedtable = ssopen.getSheetByName('IGS Closed');
  closedtable.getRange('A:BT').clearContent();

  var igs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('*URL_HERE*');
  var igsopen = igs.getSheetByName('1.a Solar Master Open');
  var igsclosed = igs.getSheetByName('1.b Solar Master Closed');
  var igsopenid = igsopen.getRange('A:BT').getValues();
  var igsopencount =igsopenid.length;
  var igsclosedid = igsclosed.getRange('A:BT').getValues();
  var igsclosedcount =igsclosedid.length;

  opentable.getRange(1,1, igsopencount, 72).setValues(igsopenid);
  closedtable.getRange(1,1, igsclosedcount, 72).setValues(igsclosedid);

}
```

Note: The URL_Here is just a placeholder for security purposes. Thanks y'all!

Comment: Try using the [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) instead of the Spreadsheet Service. The basic services are intended to make them vary easy to use, not to have a high performance.

Comment: About `Specifically, the timeout errors seem to occur on the var igs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('*URL_HERE*');.`, in your situation, even when only script of `var igs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('*URL_HERE*')` is run, such error occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Try `openById()` instead. It won't help if a cause of the error is hugeness of your base. But if there is some problem with the URL it does.